# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

Error creating bean with name 'trangchuController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

IoC.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
    ">

<context:component-scan base-package="tuan.controller"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="tuan.entity"/>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_thoitrang" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory" 
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="tuan.entity"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" 
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

**controller**

```
package tuan.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import tuan.entity.NhanVien;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class trangchuController {

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@GetMapping
@Transactional
   public String index() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        String sql = "from nhanvien";
        List<NhanVien> list = session.createQuery(sql).getResultList();

        for(NhanVien nv: list) {
             System.out.println(nv.getTenNhanVien()+" : "+nv.getTuoi());
        }
        return "trangchu";
    }
}
```

**NhanVien**

`package tuan.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

```
 @Entity(name="nhanvien")
 public class NhanVien {
     @Id
     int idNhanVien;
     String TenNhanVien;
     int Tuoi;
     public int getId() {
         return idNhanVien;
     }
     public void setId(int idNhanVien) {
         this.idNhanVien = idNhanVien;
      }
     public String getTenNhanVien() {
       return TenNhanVien;
     }
     public void setTenNhanVien(String tenNhanVien) {
          TenNhanVien = tenNhanVien;
     }
     public int getTuoi() {
          return Tuoi;
     }
      public void setTuoi(int tuoi) {
         Tuoi = tuoi;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Post code as text, not as images.

Comment: Can you please include the complete stacktrace.